# What are the differences in shapes between molecular geometry and electronic geometry?

Tags: electronic-configuration, molecular-structure

In my chemistry course we are told that molecular geometry considers only atoms as part of the shape, while electronic geometry considers atoms and electrons as part of the shape. However, I can't find any difference between the two shapes for methane online. All I can find is this:

[image: Molecular Geometry of Methane]

It confuses me that there can even be another shape for this because isn't the molecular geometry already take into consideration the fact that each molecular wants to be as far away from one another as possible? What is the difference in shape between electronic and molecular geometry?

Comment: For methane, the molecular and electronic geometries are the same. For something like NH3, which has a lone pair of electrons, they are different. @matryoshka

Comment: The term electron geometry is something which you will find in general chemistry books only (good for VSEPR only). Don't take it too literally. The is that if electron pairs are being considered, you call it electron geometry.

Comment: Electronic geometry and shapes might be used loosely as many terms. The fact that you post the Q let me think that the meaning is somehow clear to you,  and you just make sure to not misunderstand something. At a more general lexical level, electronic geometry would better refer to the electron density size and shape around atoms/molecules, and this never show up in straight edges and vertices. Something like in the pic here https://www.researchgate.net/figure/a-The-total-electron-density-surface-3D-mapped-with-electrostatic-potential-of-this_fig6_301558792  anyway ans below are correct

Answer (score 0):

**Molecular geometry** which is the **arrangement of other atoms around that central atom**.

the difference between Electron geometry and Molecular geometry is that electron geometry includes  the **lone pairs or electron around the center ** they still influence the overall geometry but when we name the shape of a molecule.

as in case of like central atom having no lone lone pair of electrons..in that case the Molecular and electron geometry of that atom would b same ; else due to presence of lone pair there would b generation of a **bent**

thats why **Methane has same Molecular and Electron geometry** 
 hope it proved helpful fr u

Answer (score -1):

The geometry of a molecule can be given as either the electron geometry or the molecular geometry. The VSEPR theory (Valence Shell Electron Pair Repulsion theory) can be used to determine the geometries of molecules. Electron geometry includes the lone electron pairs present in a molecule.

Example:
In NH3 ; same Molecular and Electron structure ; but in case of NH2. molecular and electron geometry different. Because CH4 stable structure..so it have same molecular and electron structure.
Hope it would help you